# CiviEvent: Limitations for workshop as part of a conference

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, online-registration

I created an event for a conference. The conference consists of a gernal part for every participant AND of workshops/panels with limited number of participants (each workshop/panel with its own limitations).

So I would like to
1) let participants chose which workshop/panel they would like to participate and
2) set those limitations so a workshop/panel will be set to "fully booked" (or something else) so only registrations to the waitinglis or no further registration for this whorkshop/panel will be accapted.

I know how to do the 1st part.
How to set up the 2nd part? I would be happy for any idea.

Thanks,

Zenon